# How to add an attribute to XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am very new to XML so apologies if this is a simple question;

I have the following line of code in a PHP file which is used to create a resulting line of code in an XML file via a PHP form;

```
$Savings = $xml->createElement('Savings');
```

This creates the following line in my XML file;

```
<Savings>263.4</Savings>
```

How would I change this line in my XML file to look as follows;

```
<Savings Currency="EUR">263.4</Savings>
```

I have tried the following but I get no additional output;

```
 $Savings = $xml->createElementNS('EUR', 'Savings');
```

Comment: You don't use a namespace, just an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setAttribute:

```
$Savings = $xml->createElement('Savings');
$Savings->setAttribute('Currency', 'EUR');
```